# Global Menu in KDE 5.12 + with Wayland

Tags: wayland, plasma-5, globalmenu

I use KDE in Wayland, since from 5.13 the main support for X11 will end and Wayland works much better. The only issue I face is KDEs global menu, which I am not able to use, since it is just not visible.

Is there a specific package I might need to install or something I might need to change in QT?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the main support for X11 will end" but X11 works just fine even in KDE Plasma 5.1**7**. AFAIK, even Kubuntu 20.04 will default to X11, not Wayland.• I don't use Global menus even in X11 and so can't help with that.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica I think may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/185080) and that that Kubuntu's continued support for X11 is the answer. Would you consider posting an answer?

Comment: Is supposed that the global menu of KDE (Qt applications), is supported on Wayland. Other thing is speak about the support of Gtk applications in KDE, with is several time much more complex and in Wayland ofcurse is worse. I think you should wait for a fix as it sure will come soon in the case of the Qt applications. See: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385880

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X11 will still be used by KDE Plasma in the foreseeable future. There is still a lot of work to be done as evidenced by the following quote from [KDE Decides the Three New Challenges: Wayland, Consistency, and Apps](https://dot.kde.org/2019/09/07/kde-decides-three-new-challenges-wayland-consistency-and-apps)
published in September 2019:

> Despite its many merits, the X server has become very long in the tooth, and Wayland is poised to become a more modern and dependable alternative. However, KDE's software is still quite far off from being completely implemented on the newer protocol.
>
> "As technology and the needs of modern computer users advance, X server has been proven less and less capable to keep up", says Fanis Bampaloukas, author of the first proposal. "I propose to make our goal to migrate the core of the Plasma desktop, and make X server an optional compile and runtime dependency".
>
> To achieve this goal, Fanis says KDE will have to fix major breakages and implement missing features.

Even Kubuntu 19.10 still defaults to X11.

> A Plasma Wayland session can be added by installing the package plasma-workspace-wayland, but is not officially supported. This will add a Plasma (wayland) session option at the login screen. Users needing a stable desktop experience should select the normal ‘Plasma’ (without Wayland) option at login.

Source: https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-19-10-is-released-today/

Given that 19.10 is the precursor of the next LTS to be released in April 2020, X11 will be supported by Kubuntu till at least April 2023.

So, if you use an X11 session, global menus are available for the applications that support them.

---

If you want to track the progress the KDE team is making with Wayland, monitor [Plasma/Wayland Showstoppers](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Wayland_Showstoppers).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. At the moment I am using X11 with global menus and it works fine. The reason why I wanted to switch to Wayland is that I connect and disconnect a monitor/projector during the day several times. My laptop has a 4k screen so I need to scale this up and most displays I connect are just 1080p, so not scaling needed. X11 does not support instant scaling when connecting and I need to restart the session, which is annoying. Wayland on the other hand handles that quite well.
Is there a way to achieve instant scaling on X11?

Comment: There is not reason to not support the Global Menu for the Qt applications on KDE Wayland, probably is just that you need to wait a litle. Another complete different history could be Gtk where as my know, there are not any PURE wayland applications that implement the menubar yet. Adding a support in KDE-Wayland for the Gtk-X11 applications that are running in Wayland and have a menubar i think will be much more complicated and then probably this will never be solved.